# Convert OData to csv file

Tags: python, powershell, csv, powerbi, odata

I wish to convert an OData (source Data) to a CSV file.
My data is in a HTTPS link (with username and password credentials),
and it takes too long to sync it to my PowerBI.

What I tried so far:

1. Python by downloading and saving the data as a json file and using pandas
   to convert json to csv:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('C:\dba\incidents.json')
df.to_csv('c:\\dba\\1.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8',index=False)
```

But the data is not being saved correctly.

2. Powershell: can't connect with my credentials

[image]

Does anybody have a workaround to ETL or convert an OData to CSV ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, @Sam. Please copy and paste, as text, the code you are trying to make work into the question. Only use pictures for things that cannot be best represented as text. See http://stackoverflow.com/help for more details about providing an MRE (Minimal, Reproducible Example).

Comment: My python Code: 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('C:\dba\incidents.json')
df.to_csv('c:\\dba\\1.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8',index=False)

Comment: My Powershell Code:
$USERNAME = 'crmdev@###-###.##.##'
$PASSWORD = '###*'
$IDP_URL = 'https://###.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/incidents?'
$credPair = "$($USERNAME):$($PASSWORD)"
$encodedCredentials = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($credPair))
$parameters = @{
    Uri         = $IDP_URL
    Headers     = @{ 'Authorization' = "Basic $encodedCredentials" }
    Method      = 'POST'
    Body        = '...'
    ContentType = '...'
}
Invoke-RestMethod @parameters

Comment: Result from Powershell code:

Invoke-RestMethod : The specified content type is invalid.
At line:17 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod @parameters
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], FormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.FormatException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Comment: @Sam Specify a valid content type (eg. `'application/json'`) then.